# Homebrew R vs Microsoft R

Tags: homebrew, r

I understand that math library integration is the main tweak that sets MRO apart from the CRAN R distribution, and gives it a performance advantage.

I wonder if MRO (Microsoft R Open) binaries still have a performance advantage over Homebrew R, given that both Homebrew R and Microsoft R link their binaries against Accelerate (MKL) math libraries in macOS.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience MRO is faster when using `data.table` and large datasets.

However, in Ubuntu, OS X, etc I found more convenient to use CRAN version and compile everything to avoid crashes, crossed wires, etc.

Comment: data.table performance variations are due to the fact that it needs to be compiled with openmp enabled in order to benefit from multi-core architectures. You can enable openmp in the r config when compiling data.table from CRAN source as well. It will do the trick. But don't forget to disable it afterwards.